# .htaccess - Check .jpg size and replace if match

Tags: image, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, size, jpeg

I need to control all **remotes** .jpg matching sizes: 4456 and 4824. If match these bytes I need to replace with a default image. The below code is to replace a `.jpg` if doesn't exist.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(jpeg|JPEG|jpg|JPG)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .*$ /default-image.jpg [L]
```

I need that if a `example.com/*.jpg` have size (4456 | 4824) then replace with the `default-image.jpg`.

In PHP this is working like a charm for my needs but I would prefer to set in `.htaccess`.

```
$link = 'https://example.com/test.jpg';
$check_image = get_headers($link, 1);
$bytes = $check_image["Content-Length"];    
if ($bytes < 5000) { ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following on Apache 2.4 using an Apache expression with mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/default-image\.jpg$
RewriteCond expr "filesize(%{REQUEST_FILENAME}) =~ /4456|4824/"
RewriteRule \.jpe?g$ /default-image.jpg [NC,L]
```

If the requested image does not exist then the `filesize()` function simply returns `0` (no error). So, to handle non-existent images as well, then you could just change the regex to include `0`, ie. `/0|4456|4824/`.

---

*Aside:*

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(jpeg|JPEG|jpg|JPG)$ [NC]
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
> RewriteRule .*$ /default-image.jpg [L]
> ```

In the first condition, there is no need to check `jpeg|JPEG` since you are using the `NC` (case-insensitive) flag on the directive. However, it is more optimal to perform this check in the `RewriteRule` *pattern* instead, rather than creating an additional *condition*.

There's no need to check that the request does not map to a directory (3rd *condition*), unless you also have directory names that end in `.jpg` etc. (unlikely). Filesystem checks are relatively expensive, so it is best to avoid them if possible.

Comment: Thank you MrWhite! I test your solution and is working like a charm for "local images". But if I have on hompage a remote image like src="https://example.com/test.jpg" , is not working. That is because "REQUESTED", as is a remote file, the real request is on "example.com"  Thank you also about the corrections!

Comment: Ah, I meant to ask you what you meant by "remotes .jpg". Yes, if the image is hosted on a 3rd party server then the above directive obviously won't do anything since the request is sent directly to the 3rd party server and the `.htaccess` file is bypassed entirely. But this would have also applied to your PHP script wouldn't it? Unless you are "pre-processing" the external image link in your PHP script before sending the "corrected" image link back in the HTML response?

Comment: At the final I will do'it in php. Before showing the image I will check the size and return the original or the local default one. I wanted to avoid using php for that. I think I can do'it also in a javascript file and save server resources. We talk about 80 dynamic images per page :( . Thank MrWhite and have a nice day!